# Is PDFLibNet.dll or It has any licence for commercial products?

Tags: .net, licensing, pdflib

I am using PDFLibNet.dll (got here:  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/PDFViewerControl.aspx?msg=3154388 ) am not sure whether I can use it for commercial purpose (Licence) ?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not going to get a definitive legal statement from anyone here. But -

Unfortunately that code uses lots of extra libraries that all have separate licences. From a quick glance you've got

- PDFLibNet - see the licence section on that page, [Code Project Open Licence](http://www.codeproject.com/info/cpol10.aspx)
- iTextSharp - [Affero GPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl.html) or [buy a commercial licence](http://www.itextpdf.com/terms-of-use/)
- GhostScript - [GPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html) or [buy a commercial licence](http://www.artifex.com/)
- FreeImage - GPL or [FreeImage public licence](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/freeimage-license.txt) (OK for commercial)
- Tessnet2 - [Apache 2](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html) (OK for commercial)
- The text mentions XPDF - if there's actually XPDF code here too that's also GPL or [buy a commercial licence](http://foolabs.com/xpdf/about.html)

So you'd need to buy commercial licences for a couple of components unless you're willing to release your source. Depending on how you're using the library you may be able to remove those components instead, though.

Comment: thanks for reply...I am using only PDFLibnet.dll (not other components),I am not finding Licence of that.Help me plz

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought that CodeProject page was PDFLibNet. It looks like PDFLibNet is [this project on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/pdfviewer-win32/), which is licensed under the Perl Artistic licence (OK for commercial) but it's a wrapper for either XPDF or MuPDF which are themselves GPLed. You're OK using PDFLibNet itself but you'd need to obtain a commercial licence for whichever of XPDF or MuPDF it uses under the covers.

Comment: @ Rup:"obtain a commercial licence for whichever of XPDF or MuPDF it uses under the covers" what you mean by that?...am not using any XPDF or MuPDF

Comment: If PDFLibNet is that project I linked to then the (Spanish) description says "PDF files free viewer library based on xpdf. Support MuPDF as renderer." so by including PDFLibNet you may well be including XPDF. You could try emailing the two developer addresses on that page - they could tell you for definite.